# How to git pull without overwriting database data

Tags: git, github, sqlite

I have a new project that I have cloned to a server. There is no need for full deployment since the server and my workstation are in the same room. I want to be able to make changes to my project, then push them to git, and pull them down to the live version on the server, but I don't want any of the data being inputted into the database to get overwritten.

Right now I am just using:

```
 git push origin master
```

abd on the workstation:

```
 git pull origin master
```

on the live server.

If I have the server set up as the "production environment" and the workstation using the "development environment" of the database (SQLite3), will I be overwriting any newly inputted data every time I pull from git?  What git commands should I be using in this case?

Comment: If you are using a SQLite database, you can just put the *.db file in your .gitignore (and untrack it if necessary)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm new to git, would I just type `git ignore [path of *.db file]` into my terminal?  I'd be happy to select your answer if you enter it as an answer with a little detail on how to put the file into the gitignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify that the file should be ignored in your `gitignore`. In your top-level directory, there should be a file named .gitignore (it may be hidden in your file browser.) Open that file and add `path/to/<mydb>.db`, clearly changing the path and name as appropriate.

Now, the file shouldn't be included in new commits. BUT, if you have already pushed it on previous commits, it will already be tracked by git, so the gitignore by itself probably won't work. So you might also have to run `git rm path/to/<mydb>.db` in your terminal to remove the file from the index.